# What is meaning of Operator's topics?

Tags: ros, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does the blue and the green line means in Rviz while using tutorial2 for autonomous not manually (joystick) ?

According to http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d/Tutorials/RobotOperator The blue line is  the input command. The input command `/cmd` has messeage content of (Velocity, Turn, and Mode), But `/Operator/desired` message is complete different !?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238511/what-is-meaning-of-operator%27s-topics-?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are just visualizations of the input and have the type: nav_msgs/GridCells. They show the trajectory the robot would follow given this command. In fact, only the turn is visualized, not the velocity and mode.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-06-30**:
From /cmd topic, turn has only one parameter, but /Operator/desired shows x and y. Is it because operator node convert the value of turns into locations in x and y ?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-07-01**:
Yes, the turn is the angle that the robot will turn around. So -1 is a left turn in place, 0 is a straight move and 1 a right turn in place.

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-07-12**:
Thanks a lot for all the help during my semester Sebastian :) My exam is over now and in future I will see if I can buy or make a robot, then can run with ROS then it will be fun to implement nav2d :D